# Transformation scale mutated input Bitmap but failed to recycle the original

Tags: java, android

I have this following code to scale image base on the size of the screen so it will not be destorted. my problem is i always get this error when i put this function in transformation

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transformation scale mutated input
>   Bitmap but failed to recycle the original.

```
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
      @Override
      public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {

        if (bitmap != null) {


          if (bitmap.getWidth() < MAX_WIDTH) { 
            bitmap = this.scaledDownBitmap(bitmap);
          }


          boolean flag = true;


          int deviceWidth =  ((Activity)this.context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
          int deviceHeight = ((Activity)this.context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

          int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight(); // 563
          int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth(); // 900

          // aSCPECT rATIO IS Always WIDTH x HEIGHT rEMEMMBER 1024 x 768

          if (bitmapWidth > deviceWidth) {
            flag = false;

            // scale According to WIDTH
            int scaledWidth = deviceWidth;
            int scaledHeight = (scaledWidth * bitmapHeight) / bitmapWidth;

            try {
              if (scaledHeight > deviceHeight)
                scaledHeight = deviceHeight;

              bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }

          if (flag) {
            if (bitmapHeight > deviceHeight) {
              // scale According to HEIGHT
              int scaledHeight = deviceHeight;
              int scaledWidth = (scaledHeight * bitmapWidth) / bitmapHeight;

              try {
                if (scaledWidth > deviceWidth)
                  scaledWidth = deviceWidth;

                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return bitmap;

      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a local variable Bitmap where you will reference it each time you scale the bitmap and after that you will call the recycle method of the original bitmap to release the memory of it.

**example:**

```
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {

    Bitmap bitmap2;
    Bitmap bitmap3;

    if (bitmap != null) {


      if (bitmap.getWidth() < MAX_WIDTH) { 
        bitmap = this.scaledDownBitmap(bitmap);
      }


      boolean flag = true;


      int deviceWidth =  ((Activity)this.context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
      int deviceHeight = ((Activity)this.context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

      int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight(); // 563
      int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth(); // 900

      // aSCPECT rATIO IS Always WIDTH x HEIGHT rEMEMMBER 1024 x 768

      if (bitmapWidth > deviceWidth) {
        flag = false;

        // scale According to WIDTH
        int scaledWidth = deviceWidth;
        int scaledHeight = (scaledWidth * bitmapHeight) / bitmapWidth;

        try {
          if (scaledHeight > deviceHeight)
            scaledHeight = deviceHeight;

          bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true); //reference the scaled bitmap to local bitmap
          bitmap.recycle(); //recycle the original bitmap

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      if (flag) {
        if (bitmapHeight > deviceHeight) {
          // scale According to HEIGHT
          int scaledHeight = deviceHeight;
          int scaledWidth = (scaledHeight * bitmapWidth) / bitmapHeight;

          try {
            if (scaledWidth > deviceWidth)
              scaledWidth = deviceWidth;

            bitmap3 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true);
            bitmap2.recycle();
            return bitmap3;

          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return bitmap2;

  }
```

Comment: i get this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Transformation scale returned null after 0 previous transformation(s).

Comment: should i still recycle image on this part   bitmap = this.scaledDownBitmap(bitmap); ?

Comment: nah. forget it. it was fine :). hanks